# Can I sync my Mac with Office 365 Exchange?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, sync, exchange, office365

Can I sync my Mac with Office 365 Exchange? I know that the Mac doesn't support sync via Exchange Active Sync, but does Office 365 support Exchange Web Services?

I'd really like to sync Mail/iCal/Addressbook with Office 365.

Running Mac OS X 10.7.

Comment: @KCotreau I've seen this page. They don't mention it directly but indeed it sounds as if Exchange Web Aervices are available. Maybe I'll try the 30 day trial and test it directly. Please move your comment to an answer, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with the native OSX apps (iCal, Mail, Address book) on Lion!

You just need to add an Exchange account in the OSX system settings at "mail, contacts, calendar" - really simple!

However, I have a case here where autodiscover does not work (a certificate error is returned when setting up the account, obviously because the domain is not fully delegated to MS on the internal DNS servers of the previous provider). Here, it gets difficult because in the accounts wizard of OSX you do not get the chance to enter the server name (sth. like `podxxxxx.outlook.com`) manually.

Here, **iCal** is the relief, it seems to be more tolerant:

- Start iCal, go to options (`cmd - ,`)
- Click accounts, click the plus
- Choose type "Exchange", and enter your email address, and a nonsense password, click *Create account*.
- When the wrong certificate is shown, do not accept it (repeatedly). After a few errors/clicks, you get a dialog where you can manually enter the server name!
- Here, enter `podxxxx.outlook.com` and your correct password.
- After doing so, iCal should work with Office 365.

The account will also be listed in the system settings, and you can just switch on Mail and Contacts.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these details.  
I've also found the following guide for Mail: http://www.configureoffice365.com/configure-office-365-mac-mail-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

It would seem like yes. Follow the instructions here:

http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/hh180727.aspx (go to "Configure Outlook 2011 for Office 365").

These links may also be helpful:

http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/ff637594.aspx

http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/ff637585.aspx

http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/ff652542.aspx

Comment: I moved it and added a few more links that may help when you try it.

Comment: These instructions are all for Outlook 2011. But I'd like to sync the native Mac Mail/iCal/Addressbook applications which all support Exchange via Exchange Web Services, not Exchange Active Sync.
So it seems rather NO for now.